# Linq- Join, Max(Date)

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with converting SQL query to LINQ

```
    SELECT * FROM Log x
    JOIN (SELECT p.objId,
                 MAX(modifiedDateTime) AS latestDateTime
          FROM Log p
          GROUP BY p.objId) y ON y.objId= x.objId
                                 AND y.latestDateTime = x.modifiedDateTime
```

Please suggest. This is where I got so far

```
    var query1 = from x in query
                 join y in query
                 on new {x.objId, x.modifiedDateTime}
                 equals new {y.objId, ...(Max)}
```

Answer (score 1):

the two new anonymous objects you create won't ever be equal. You need to compare the values to one another directly. Try:
on x.objID equals y.objID && x.modifiedDateTime equals y.lastestDateTime